# Как заполнить домик градиентом?

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

Мне нужно сверстать вот такой домик, и что бы можно было в % задавать скажем высоту блока с градиентом и он на эту высоту устанавливался, все что у меня есть это серая рамка домика в .png и градиент в виде:

```
'background-image: linear-gradient(51deg, #009f4d 0%, #97d700 100%);'
```

Я пробовал вставлять картинку и с помощью z-index градиент запихивать под картинку, но он пихается вместо background а не вместо серой границы домика. Подскажите как это можно реализовать с помощью HTML + CSS. Спасибо.

[image: 1]]

Comment: покажи, как пытался реализовать....

Comment: С png нужно инвертировать его, т.е. сам домик должен быть прозрачной дыркой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, такие штуки, скорее всего, элегантно делаются на svg, но при должной сноровке можно и на старом-добром CSS смастерить. С размерами и адаптивностью поиграйтесь сами:

```css
.domik {
  margin: 120px 0 0 30px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(51deg, #009f4d 0%, #97d700 100%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.domik:before,
.domik:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.domik:before {
  border: 20px solid silver;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 147px;
  height: 147px;
  top: -63px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.domik:after {
  background-color: white;
  width: 145px;
  height: 145px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  top: -45px;
}
.inner {
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.inner b {
  font-size: 38px;
}
.inner:before,
.inner:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 16px;
}
.inner:before {
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  background-color: #47b928;
}
.inner:after {
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  background-color: #89d107;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="domik">
  <div class="inner">
    <b>72.09%</b><br />
    Remaining equity
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите принцип, как это сделать на SVG?

Comment: @ДимаСвободин, svg не владею, к сожалению